# Save custom page number labels in bookmarks

Tags: java, pdfbox

In the screenshot you can see custom page number labels (i, ii, iii, vii).

[image]

How can I save bookmarks with custom page number labels using PDFBox 2.0?

My code actually looks like this:

```java
PDDocumentOutline documentOutline =  new PDDocumentOutline();
document.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline(documentOutline);
PDOutlineItem outline = new PDOutlineItem();
outline.setTitle(toc.getName());
documentOutline.addLast(outline);
addToc(toc, outline);
outline.openNode();
documentOutline.openNode();
```

```java
private void addToc(Toc toc, PDOutlineItem outlineItem) {
    PDPageFitWidthDestination destination = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
    PDPage page = document.getPage(toc.getPageNumber() - 1);
    destination.setPage(page);
    PDOutlineItem bookmark = new PDOutlineItem();
    bookmark.setDestination(destination);
    bookmark.setTitle(toc.getName());
    outlineItem.addLast(bookmark);

    if (toc.getChildren() != null) {
        for (Toc subToc : toc.getChildren()) {
            addToc(subToc, bookmark);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only label pages, not bookmarks. In the example below (with 3 empty pages), roman numbers start at 3, and then decimal at 1. The prefix for the romans is "RO ". So the pages are "RO III", "RO IV", "1".

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
doc.addPage(new PDPage());
doc.addPage(new PDPage());
doc.addPage(new PDPage());
PDPageLabels pageLabels = new PDPageLabels(doc);
PDPageLabelRange pageLabelRange1 = new PDPageLabelRange();
pageLabelRange1.setPrefix("RO ");
pageLabelRange1.setStart(3);
pageLabelRange1.setStyle(PDPageLabelRange.STYLE_ROMAN_UPPER);
pageLabels.setLabelItem(0, pageLabelRange1);
PDPageLabelRange pageLabelRange2 = new PDPageLabelRange();
pageLabelRange2.setStart(1);
pageLabelRange2.setStyle(PDPageLabelRange.STYLE_DECIMAL);
pageLabels.setLabelItem(2, pageLabelRange2);
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setPageLabels(pageLabels);
doc.save("labels.pdf");
doc.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Tilman. I thought it is possible to use custom labels. I have labels like " - " or "[123]" in our digitization metadata and wanted to use the exact labels in the PDF. Maybe I should write it to a bookmark title prefix then...

Comment: Just to be sure, I looked at the PDF specification, but there is no "custom" labelling scheme, not even in PDF 2.0. There's really just the stuff from our API.